# Wordpress Development Cycle

Tags: mysql, wordpress, beta

I have built a WordPress site. I have hired a developer to work on it.
My developer works in my beta site. I cannot give him access to the live site's admin or SQL back-end.

Once the developer has completed the work he is contracted to do, I am not sure how to merge his changes into my live site.

To simply copy all SQL tables and files is not an option.
To copy the files alone would be no problem but the databases will be slightly different, particularly the users table and tables whose referential integrity depends on the users table.

Where do I begin to learn the best practice for this?

Comment: you can start on [another forum](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: A related question is [Override database config for WordPress multiblog](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2348/override-database-config-for-wordpress-multiblog)

Comment: If you changed the database structure you need to create migration scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You could look into [BackupBuddy](http://ithemes.com/purchase/backupbuddy/), we use it here all the time and it works great for copying files/databases just from the wordpress admin and site.com/importbuddy.php. [WPTwin](http://wptwin.com/) is also very good, it's easier to use, but it's also not nearly as thorough

Comment: +1 BackupBuddy is a fabulous tool.